# How do I match an element that has a certain sibling element in xslt/xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to match all `a/c` elements that have a `b` sibling. I've tried:

```
<xsl:template match="a/b/../c">
```

but I get "Cannot convert the expression {..} to a pattern" from Saxon.

My XSLT/XPath skills are basic at best...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="a[b]/c">
```

Explanation: match any `c` element that is a child of an `a` element that has a `b` child.

You should also be able to use `..` in a predicate:

```
<xsl:template match="a/c[../b]">
```

which is similar to what you were trying.

The reason you can't use `..` directly in a match pattern (i.e. outside of a predicate) is that patterns are not XPath expressions, even though they look and behave very similarly. In particular, only "downward" axes (`child::`, `descendant::`, and `attribute::`) are allowed directly in patterns. (The only explicit axes allowed by the spec are `child::` and `attribute::`. `descendant::` is implicitly allowed via the `//` between [pattern steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#NT-RelativePathPattern). Saxon seems to bend the rules a bit here, allowing an explicit `descendant::` axis, and even `descendant-or-self::`!)

The reason given for the restriction on axes is that (a) other axes are rarely needed in patterns, and (b) this allows XSLT processors to be much more efficient in testing for matches.

But **predicates** in patterns *are* defined with the [same syntax rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#NT-StepPattern) as in XPath expressions (with some restrictions in XSLT 1.0, like not allowing variable references or `current()`). So you can use other axes, like `parent::`, or the abbreviation `..`.

Comment: thanks - this is so helpful. I eventually discovered that `..` could be used in a predicate (shortly after discovering what a predicate was), but I was clueless as to the explanation and this answer is just what I was hoping for and more - it helps me understand.

Comment: plus `a[b]/c` is neater than what I came up with :-)

Answer (score 1):

This XPath expression seems to do the job (may be not optimal):

```
//a|//c[following-sibling::b or preceding-sibling::b]
```

Edit:

In case LarsH is right, it should be `//a/c` instead of `//a|//c`.

Comment: I believe when the OP says `a/c` he means "`c` element that's a child of an `a`", not "`a` or `c`".

Comment: Also, you can omit `//` at the beginning of a match pattern.

Comment: @LarsH you are correct. Lev sorry if I was not clear - please do say if I should have expressed my problem differently as that will help me learn!

Comment: @Jack No, I guess it was my fault :)LarsH, `//` was needed for the tool I was testing it with.